# Modifying Pandas code for PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following snippet of code which is used to create a graph. I want to modify it to work in PySpark but am not sure how to proceed. The issue is I can't iterate over a column in PySpark and I have unsuccessfully tried making this into a function.

Context: The DataFrame has a column called `City` which is just the name of the city as a string

```
cities = [i.City for i in df.select('City').distinct().collect()]

stack = [] 

for city in cities:
    df = sqlContext.sql(   'SELECT Complaint Type, COUNT(*) as `counts` '
                           'FROM c311 '
                           'WHERE City = "{}" COLLATE NOCASE '
                           'GROUP BY `Complaint Type` '
                           'ORDER BY counts DESC'.format(city))

    stack.append(Bar(x=df['Complaint Type'], y=df.counts, name=city.capitalize()))
```

My goal is then to send this `toPandas()` and graph it locally. However I am encountering errors since `Column is not iterable`. How do I approach this for PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import upper, col

pdf = df.withColumn("city", upper(col("city"))) \
    .groupBy("Complaint Type").pivot("city").count() \
    .toPandas()
```

(or group by `city` and pivot by `type`) and use it from there.